# Split into list of list and convert specific element of it to integer in python

Tags: python

Suppose we have a string:

```
A = "John\t20\nChris\t30\nAby\t10\n"
```

I want to make `A` into a list of list with the first element still `str` and second element converted to `int`:

What i have done is :

```
A = [[lambda k,v: str(k), int(v) for k, v in s.split('\t')] for s in A.split('\n')]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the values without `lambda`:

`[[s.split('\t')[0], int(s.split('\t')[1])] for s in A.strip().split('\n')]`

Note: strip() is added to parse out the trailing '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating this. You don't need an anonymous function here at all.

First, `split` the string, then iterate over groups of two from the resulting list and convert the second element of the pairs to `int`.

For the second part, the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a recipe called **`grouper`**. You can either copy-paste the function or import it from [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) (which needs to be installed).

```
>>> from more_itertools import grouper
>>>
>>> a = "John\t20\nChris\t30\nAby\t10\n"
>>> [(s, int(n)) for s, n in grouper(2, a.split())]
[('John', 20), ('Chris', 30), ('Aby', 10)]
```

Finally, if you want to flatten the result, apply [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((s, int(n)) for s, n in grouper(2, a.split())))
['John', 20, 'Chris', 30, 'Aby', 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use lambda, here's a simpler way;

```
L = lambda s: [s.split('\t')[0], int(s.split('\t')[1])]
A3 = [L(x) for x in A.strip().split('\n')]
```